# "x-default" needed in hreflang?

Tags: hreflang

Would I be right in thinking I need to set the following to what it states below in this image?

I am basically wondering if I need to add `hreflang="x-default"` to this section below.

[image: Screenshot of the markup]

Comment: Can you edit your question to insert the code directly rather than via an image? Code in images isn't searchable, which doesn't help future visitors. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, mate, i did try adding the code, but for some reason this site only excepted one line, so had to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

`x-default` hreflang attribute specifies that a page doesn’t target any specific language. In your example you are clear referring to two main languages without having a *neutral* page for selecting between them, so in your case it is not necessary.